# como imprimo un mensaje personalizado partiendo de una variable que tengo mi archivo php en ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Este es mi `AJAX`..

```
<!-- CREATE AJAX -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#create').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "usuario_registrado.php",
                    method: "post",
                    dataType: "text",
                    data:$('form').serialize(),
                    success: function(resultado){
                        if($error_enviado == true){ 
                               $('#mensaje').html("<p>"+resultado+"</p>")
                         }else{
                             $('mensaje').html("<p>"+resultado+"</p>")
                        }
                    } 
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
```

y este mi php..

```
<?php 
include("includes/motor.php");
$users = new Usuarios();

if ($_POST) {

        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $nacimiento = $_POST['fecha'];
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
        $usuario = $_POST['user'];
        $privilegio = $_POST['privilegio'];
        $clave1 = $_POST['clave1'];
        $clave2 = $_POST['clave2'];
        $error_enviado="";
        $error_pass ="";

        if($nombre == "" || $apellido == "" || $email == "" || $nacimiento == "" || $telefono == "" || $usuario == "" || $privilegio == "" || $clave1 == "" || $clave == ""){

             echo "<div class='alert alert-danger text-center' role='alert' style='padding:10px;'>¡Debes rellenar todos los campos!</div>";

?>
```

quiero que si se cumple la condición me imprima un mensaje, sino, que haga otro.. pero todo usando mi `ajax`

Comment: Bienvenido para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio te invito a dar un [tour]. Es muy importante **que leas** [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo suelo crear un array en el back y lo retorno al front convertido a JSON. Este array siempre lo llamo `$data` y dentro de el suelo poner como llaves `success` y `message`.

`Success` lo utilizo para saber si la operación que quiero realizar fue éxitosa o no. Mientras que `message` hace que retorne el mensaje personalizado dependiendo de la acción.

Trataré de guiarme un poco con la información que has dado, y de la manera en que te lo estoy mencionando.

### PHP

```
<?php 
    include("includes/motor.php");
    $users = new Usuarios();

    if ($_POST) {
       $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
       $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $nacimiento = $_POST['fecha'];
       $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
       $usuario = $_POST['user'];
       $privilegio = $_POST['privilegio'];
       $clave1 = $_POST['clave1'];
       $clave2 = $_POST['clave2'];
       $error_enviado="";
       $error_pass ="";

       if($nombre == "" || $apellido == "" || $email == "" || $nacimiento == "" || $telefono == "" || $usuario == "" || $privilegio == "" || $clave1 == "" || $clave == ""){
          $data['success'] = false;
          $data['message'] = "Tienes que llenar todos los campos.";
       } else {
          $data['success'] = true;
          $data['message'] = "Todos tus campos están llenos :)";
       }

     return json_encode($data);
?>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#create').click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
         url: "usuario_registrado.php",
         method: "post",
         dataType: "text",
         data:$('form').serialize(),
         success: function(data){
            console.log(data) //Checa tu consola del navegador.
            if(data.success){
              $('#message').html("<p class='alert alert-success text-center'>"+data.message+"</p>");
             } else {
              $('#message').html("<p class='alert alert-danger text-center'>"+data.message+"</p>");
             }
         } 
      });
 });
```

Comment: graciass!! pruebo y te digo.. en caso que tenga mas de un if, lo que hago es añadir mas succes

Comment: me dice undifined , en el div

Comment: Qué te imprime la consola del navegador?

Comment: nada, en blanco

Comment: @ebrainmachado Añadí un json_encode en el return de PHP. Checalo, por favor. También corregí el código.

Comment: pues con el json encode no funca tampoco. sabes que el error que da es que en en div del mensaje en vez de retornar las cadenas de texto, coloca es "undefined"

Comment: No regreses el div del back PHP. Regresa solo una cadena de texto con el mensaje. En jQuery tu lo añades a un div.

Comment: estoy haciendo copy y paste de tu codigo y no funca, el div lo tengo en el html ...

Comment: Añade un die; después del return en el PHP.

Comment: no working man, ya mañana me siento  a revisar el codigo bien a ver . al menos me das una idea y eso te lo agradezco, gracias..

Comment: si quiere validad si todos los campos este llenos lo mejor es utilizar la propiedad required aqui tiene un link para ver el ejemplo: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: te comento @Hoose que hice un "echo" a las variables data y pues me retonar el valor... ahora bien , en la cosola solo me esta devolviendo la funcion con el valor 1 , es decir que siempre es true.. no me esta validando el false

Comment: ¿Podrías editar esta pregunta con el código que estas poniendo tu mismo?

Answer (score 0):

si quiere mesajes personalizado instale esta librería aqui esta el link de la pagina 
https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script>
success: function(resultado){                                          
swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
}    
</script>
```

Comment: necesito que dependiendo si se cumple o no el if , el coloque el mensaje en el modal .. gracias por tu respuesta marcos